# Some JSON API error - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: python, json, rest

If I run this code:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.icicidirect.com")
payload = json.dumps({})
#time_stamp & checksum generation for request-headers
time_stamp = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:19] + '.000Z'
checksum = hashlib.sha256((time_stamp+payload+API_SECRET).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Checksum': checksum,
    'X-Timestamp': time_stamp,
    'X-AppKey': API_KEY,
    'X-SessionToken': Session_Token
}
conn.request("GET", "/breezeapi/api/v1/dematholdings", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

I get:

> {"Status":5,"Error":"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."}

After referring to the **documentation**, https://api.icicidirect.com/breezeapi/documents/index.html?python#dematholdings.

**Question**: Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't think that's a JSON error.

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with one of the X-xxx headers.

Comment: Someone else reported a similar error to their community forum: https://community.icicidirect.com/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array-or-string but there's no solution given.

Comment: @Barmar - this icicidirect's breeze-connect module is not a valid tag in StackOverFlow. Is it possible to add a tag to attract users and developers here?

Comment: You can request the tag at [meta]

Comment: I also have the same issue in JavaScript SDK. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The ICIC Direct Breeze API works like this

1. You have to log in using their SSO -

Request:
https://api.icicidirect.com/apiuser/login?api_key=AppKey

Response:
You will get `sessionkey` or `API_session` in URL

2. you have to call the customer details API using that `sessionKey` from point 1.

Then you will get a response like this:

```
{
    "Success": {
        "exg_trade_date": {
            "NSE": "28-Sep-2022",
            "BSE": "28-Sep-2022",
            "FNO": "28-Sep-2022",
            "NDX": "28-Sep-2022"
        },
        "exg_status": {
            "NSE": "O",
            "BSE": "O",
            "FNO": "O",
            "NDX": "O"
        },
        "segments_allowed": {
            "Trading": "Y",
            "Equity": "Y",
            "Derivatives": "Y",
            "Currency": "Y"
        },
        "idirect_userid": "AF077290",
        **"session_token": "ABCwNzcyOTA6MTA5NDM3NTQ=",**
        "idirect_user_name": "APPADURAI   ARAVIND",
        "idirect_ORD_TYP": "",
        "idirect_lastlogin_time": "28-Sep-2022 12:53:51",
        "mf_holding_mode_popup_flg": "N",
        "commodity_exchange_status": "O",
        "commodity_trade_date": "28-Sep-2022",
        "commodity_allowed": "O"
    },
    "Status": 200,
    "Error": null
}
```

Here `Success.session_token` is the actual session token you have to use for all other API calls. Same has been mentioned in the document clearly.

Here is my working API

[image]

Source code can be found on: https://github.com/Aravin/Algo-Trade (in JavaScript)